# Create Panda DataFrame from Nested List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a panda dataframe from nested list that contains ndarray inside below:

```
from numpy import array
a = list([[1,2],[2,3]])                  
a[0] = array([[1,2]])
a[0][0] = array([1,2])
```

what I want to achieve is below:

```
 D0    D1  
 1     2   
 2     3
```

I've tried just using

```
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

which creates

```
   D0      
 [1,2]        
 [2,3]
```

I also tried using pd.append inside the for loop

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(a[i]))
```

which achieves what I want but it's extremely slow and somehow the df.append creates duplicates.

Please help.

Thx in advance.

Comment: pd.DataFrame(a) works well on my side

Comment: @Wen due to the weird nested list with ndarray (with a nested array inside), pd.DataFrame(a) smashes everything into the same column.

Comment: @jpp My real data contains length of 420091 array and each array has 256 elements inside. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: @pault No. It's float.

Comment: @SwagZ Try something like `df = pd.DataFrame(array.tolist())`, or `df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in array])`. Whichever works

Answer (score 7):

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a list of lists directly. There is no need to redefine list elements as `numpy` arrays.

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['D0', 'D1'])

print(df)

#    D0  D1
# 0   1   2
# 1   2   3
```